# Ubuntu: Netplan dont remove Nameserver

Tags: ubuntu, resolv.conf, netplan

iam running ubuntu 22.04 on hetzner. After changing the nameservers with netplan, the old nameserver still show up resolvectl status and /etc/resolve.conf.

Removing them from resolve.conf does not work, after reboot they are back.

Is there a way to remove them permantly?

resolvectl status:

```
Global
       Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
resolv.conf mode: uplink
     DNS Servers: 1.1.1.1

Link 2 (eth0)
Current Scopes: DNS
     Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
   DNS Servers: 1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1 185.12.64.1 185.12.64.2
```

My netplan:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      addresses:
      - 2a01:4f8:1c1c:7ae4::1/64
      dhcp4: true
      match:
        macaddress: '96:00:02:36:57:38'
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 1.1.1.1
        - 1.0.0.1
      routes:
      - on-link: true
        to: default
        via: fe80::1
      set-name: eth0
  version: 2
```